# How do I uninstall a Visual Studio Code extension without using the GUI?

Tags: command-line, visual-studio-code

I installed an extension that was making Visual Studio Code extremely slow, by maxing out all cores and slowing the system down to a crawl.

How can I uninstall it and make Visual Studio Code usable again?

I obviously can't use the GUI because the extension is loaded on startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me was the following:

1. First, find the extension ID:

   `code --list-extensions`

   You might have to guess, but for me, the offending extension ID was `rust-lang.rust`. (I'm not saying the extension is bad, it just didn't work well on my laptop.)
2. Then, uninstall it:

   `code --uninstall-extension ID`

   (You need to replace `ID` with the ID you found in step one, so I had to execute `code --uninstall-extension rust-lang.rust`)

That's pretty much all there is to it, but note that the uninstall step might not have removed external dependencies, for example.